# Server Error Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component in _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am a newbie in React and Next JS, I want to set initial auth user data on initial load from the __app.js. But using dispatch throwing error "Invalid hook call". I know according to docs calling hooks in render function is wrong. but I am looking for an alternate solution to this.

How I can set auth data one-time so that will be available for all the pages and components.

I am including my code below.

**/contexts/app.js**

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext } from 'react'

const AppStateContext    = createContext()
const AppDispatchContext = createContext()

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_AUTH': {
      return state = action.payload 
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}`)
    }
  }
}

export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})

  return (
    <AppDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <AppStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </AppStateContext.Provider>
    </AppDispatchContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAuth         = () => useContext(AppStateContext)
export const useDispatchAuth = () => useContext(AppDispatchContext)
```

**/_app.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import App from 'next/app'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { mutate } from 'swr'
import { getUser } from '../requests/userApi'
import { AppProvider, useDispatchAuth } from '../contexts/app'

class MyApp extends App {

  render() {
    const dispatchAuth = useDispatchAuth()
    const { Component, pageProps, props } = this.props
   
    // Set initial user data
    const setInitialUserData = async () => {
      if (props.isServer) {
        const initialData = {
          loading: false,
          loggedIn: (props.user) ? true : false,
          user: props.user
        }
    
        const auth = await mutate('api-user', initialData, false)

        dispatchAuth({
          type: 'SET_AUTH',
          payload: auth
        })
      }
    }
    //----------------------

    // Set initial user data
    setInitialUserData()
    //----------------------

    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </AppProvider>
    )
  }
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  let isServer  = (appContext.ctx.req) ? true : false
  let user      = null
  let userTypes = {}

  // Get user server side
  if (isServer) {
    await getUser()
    .then(response => {
      let data = response.data
      
      if (data.status == true) {
        // Set user
        user      = data.data.user
        userTypes = data.data.user_types
        //---------
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //
    })
  }
  //---------------------

  return { 
    props: { 
      user,
      userTypes,
      isServer
    }
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: React hooks are only compatible with functional components, you are trying to use `useDispatchAuth` in `App` which is a class-based component. You'll have to use the Context API to read the context and pass the context value to `MyApp` via props.

Comment: @DrewReese can you please share an example code for this.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer

Comment: hooks are used only with functional components

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the intended use of the useEffect hook with an empty array as its second argument:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'

class MyApp extends App {

useEffect(()=> {
 setInitialUserData()
},[])

  render() {
...
}
```

}

Comment: Using useEffect here giving syntax error.

Comment: React hooks are not compatible with class components. This won't work.